# Send a cookie to the browser when using Vue and node

Tags: node.js, express, vuejs2

I'm running my client side on port 8080 using Vue 3 and I'm running my server on port 8081 using node and express.

When I log a user in my node application sends the cookie but it isn't showing up in the browser.

I have been told that it is because the browser and the server are running on different ports, is this true and how do I fix this?

Comment: It could also be that the server is setting the cookie with HttpOnly. In that case, you can't get it with JavaScript

Comment: Yes I am setting the httpOnly to true when I create the cookieOptions. What should I do to enable the client side to receive this token?

Comment: Then you may not set httpOnly to true, but this opens some security risks like XSS attacks. If you want to pass a token that you need to use in the front end, instead of using cookies, you could also set a HTTP header instead or place the token in the body of the response

Comment: Yes putting the token in the body when sending it to the front is what I'm probably going to have to do.